# Lua Service2Media Mobile

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, lua

Im trying to create a map using the service2media platform for mobile applications and i get this error - attempted index of non table : null on the line where i create a new map instance. Any idea why? The map view takes in coordinates and radius as parameters.

```
MapView ={}

function MapView:loadView()

local mapView = M2Map.newNativeMapView(Coordinate(0,0), 3000);
self:addSubView(mapView);

end
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to instantiate the Coordinate class using Coordinate.new(). Depending on the version of the platform you possibly have to use the MapView class instead of the M2Map class. In the latter case you have to rename your Lua class name in order to prevent name collision.

```
function MapView:loadView()
    local mapView = M2Map.newNativeMapView(Coordinate.new(0,0), 3000);
    self:addSubView(mapView);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes i did say Coodinate.new(0,0) but forgot to mention it on the code here. and There is no MapView in the platform i am using therefore i have to use M2Maps